# Update variables using multiple values returned from a function in Scala

Tags: scala

Assume I have a function that return multiple values in scala.

```
def foo:(Double, Double) = {
    (1.1, 2.2)
}
```

I can call it as below without a problem.

```
val bar = foo
```

or

```
val (x, y) = foo
```

However, if I try to update existing variables like below, it doesn't work.

```
var x = 1.0
var y = 2.0
(x, y) = foo
```

This returns an error saying `error: ';' expected but '=' found`

Is there any reason behind this. Why can't I update the existing variables using `(x, y) = foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for multiple assignment is actually an example of pattern matching. So this

```
val (x, y) = foo
...
```

is sort of equivalent to

```
foo match {
  case (x, y) =>
    ...
```

This means that you can use more advanced pattern matching syntax like this:

```
val f @ (x, y) = foo
```

or this

```
val (x, _) = foo
```

But pattern matching can only be used to extract values into new variables, it can't be used to update existing variables, which is why the last bit of code does not compile. Scala code tends to avoid `var` anyway, so this is not a major problem for most programs.

Comment: I am doing some tradtional CS  algorithms and these tend to use var's more frequently than general scala code. In this case updating var's would have been nice to have.

Comment: You can convert many traditional algorithms to functional code by replacing `while` loops with recursive calls.

Comment: Yea but let's just say that recursive calls are not the easiest things to do under time pressure - and they're often pretty not readable.  I am not a *pure* functional programmer and have no interest in being one. I am mostly forced into python on my ML/AI job so it is impractical to write code that I find mildly challenging and  others on the team would have no chance of getting. Also can be more inefficient

Comment: Porting imperative algorithms to functional Scala under time pressure is never going to be easy, especially if you are not comfortable with recursive code. So I would stick with the imperative version and either make the `var` a tuple or add the extra lines of code needed to copy the return values from the tuple into separate `var`s.